# How to refresh telerik:RadGrid Batch Editing state with out post back

Tags: javascript, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

Looking for javascript Method  which will force client rebind of the **telerik:RadGrid** Batch Editing and will 
refresh its state with out post back

I used bellow syntax to refresh grid state,it’s not working

```
function assignDataSourceAndRefresh()
{
    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    masterTable.dataBind();
}
```

I also used bellow syntax it’s working but it’s make a post back.i need a process which refresh grid state without postback

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnRefresh" Text="Refresh" AutoPostBack="false" OnClientClicked="testRefresh"></telerik:RadButton>


function testRefresh(sender, args) {
    var batchManager = $find('<%=RadGrid2.ClientID%>').get_batchEditingManager();            
    batchManager.cancelChanges($find('<%=RadGrid2.ClientID%>').get_masterTableView());          
}
```

**Note :** please any one not suggest me to use RadClientDataSource for my grid,to fill my grid i used Bellow syntax.

```
function assignDataSourceAndRefresh()
{
    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    masterTable.set_dataSource(<some_data_source_of_the_specified_type_above>);
    masterTable.dataBind();
}
```

Comment: How do you call `testRefresh`?  if its on a button click, you need to return false so that it doesnt post back. Or set `AutoPostBack = false`

Comment: paqogomez, thank fro your reply. i put my button on my question description,please check it, yes i set button AutoPostBack=false

Comment: Are you using `RadAjaxManager`?

Comment: Also, put `return false` into your function.

Comment: paqogomez,no i don't use the  RadAjaxManager.If RadAjaxManager is the only way to refresh grid state with out post back then please show me the guideline how to?

Comment: paqogomez, i put return false on my javascript method testRefresh() but it's still do a postback then refresh grid state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72594/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-shamim).

Comment: You do realize that if you are getting new data, you have to do a *partial postback* right?  Thats what ajax is, partial postbacks, not full postbacks.

Comment: paqogomez, in my page i can not use ajax post back process. thanks for your valuable information